# Guake transparency not working

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, gnome, transparency

I would like to recover transparency on Guake on my workstation (`CentOs 6.4, linux 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64`)
I use it for a long time on Suse or Ubuntu, I already know how to adjust transparency.

I tried this solution:

> run
>
> **`gnome-session-properties`**
>
> under startup-programs edit your entry for Guake.
>
> and add  **`sleep 8 &&`** infront of guake, like so
>
> **`sleep 8 && guake`**

This gives guake an 8 second delay before starting, and should be enough to let Gnome fully initialize, and your transparency will work as it should ref. [cgerada](http://cgerada.blogspot.fr/2012/01/resolve-transparency-issues-with-guake.html).

But it changes nothing.

Have you any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You must edit /usr/bin/guake and after the line `from_future_import abosolute import` add

```
import time
time.sleep(8)
```

and save the file... thats it transparency working again!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the Startup Application preferences, put the below command to start Guake after a delay of 5 seconds. It worked for me.

```
bash -c 'sleep 5s; /usr/bin/guake'
```